# How to test forms with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, forms, unit-testing, jasmine

I just started learning Jasmine and everything works fine apart from testing the form

I'm creating a todo app. Users submit the form and the input content is pushed to todos array.

This is the test

```
it('should trigger form', function(){
    document.body.innerHTML += '<form><input value="get milk" /><button type="submit" /></form>'
    const form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0]
    const result = 'get milk'
    const value = ''
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('it happened')
      value = document.querySelector('input').value
    })
    setTimeout(function(){form.submit()}, 3000)
    expect(value).toEqual(result)
    // Then I'll remove the form from the dom
  })
```

The form get's submitted but the event listener doesn't get triggered, so the page keeps reloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no possible way to test what is happening after the submission. So, an option would be to remove the `addEventListener`, `spyOn` the `submit` function of the form and mock the implementation.

```
    spyOn(form, 'submit').and.callFake(function() {
        console.log('it happened');
        value = document.querySelector('input').value;
        return false;
    });
```

Also, if you want to keep the `setTimeout`, you will need to use the `it`'s optional single argument that should be called when the async work is complete, and move your `expect` inside the `setTimeout` function.

```
it('should trigger form', function(done/*call this function to complete the test*/){
    //...some code here

    setTimeout(function(){
        form.submit();

        expect(value).toEqual(result); // move "expect" here

        done(); // call "done" to complete the test
        }, 3000);
}
```

Hope it helps